# Entity Framework 6 database migrations for isolated multi-tenant setup

Tags: c#, asp.net, multi-tenant, entity-framework-6

I understand database migrations might not be the best method to deploy this solution, so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I have x identical database schemas, one per client.

I also have models for each one of these databases and am able to deploy a migration which creates a new clone. Up until this point, I had been using PHP and scripts to loop through all the schemas and update any changes to the structure. We are moving over to C# and EF6 due to Web API 2 and attribute routing.

My question is; Is there a way to:

1. Deploy a build command which will do what `update-database` would do for a migration, and pass it a database name (in order to create a new clone schema of the account database?
2. Deploy a build command which might do what `update-database` would do recursively through each one of the target databases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "I have x identical database schemas, one per client  "
>   and
>   "I also have models for each one of these databases"

Did you mean  I also have models for each one of these Schemas?

Ef model entities are linked to a Schema/TableName.

> entity.ToTable("tableName", "schemaName");

So if each client gets their own schema, then each model has all tables in that schema and the client gets their own model. 
So how do I run update-database on each Context model. I another way of looking at the issue.

So the answer lies with how you are tracking the schema per client info.

[Powershell migrate.exe approach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618307) might be interest for your so that you can trigger migration on many context models.

[Custom migration operations](http://romiller.com/2013/02/27/ef6-writing-your-own-code-first-migration-operations/) might also be interesting. Rowan is an EF developer.

**EDIT: based on Auto Migration comment, this is worth a look**
[Managing migration triggers in code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20255859/1347784)

Comment: Thanks Phil. For clarification: I have a set of models which build a database schema which is then cloned multiple times, once per client. Connecting to the right context is not an issue I have set up a handler for that. I also discovered that I am able to use context.Database.CreateIfNotExists() to create a new database. I will have a look at the tools you linked, thanks. I have an inkling that this is the right answer, so I'll go ahead and mark it. I feel like I did not do enough research on the matter in the first place.

Comment: if you are going to use Automated Migrations, then you can loop over your client database list and trigger Migrate.  Ill add a link shortly

Comment: Legendary! Thanks Phil :)

Comment: Don't use EF Migrations for updating tenants.. it can get really complicated and hairy if something breaks and the error messages are useless. Better use a SQL Project and use SQL Packages. Much better visibility and deployment strategies can be used.