# EF migrations not updating the database automatically

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, entity-framework-migrations

I have EF migrations enabled and want to update an existing database running in azure. When I run the application I get the following exception:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The model backing the 'MyContext' context has
>   changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First
>   Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

However I have migrations enabled.

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, Configuration>());
```

And

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
         AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;//have also tried true
    }
}
```

Up until this latest commit everything has worked automatically as expected and i haven't changed the initialization code (only added new migrations).

If i download the database and run the app I get the same result. However if I manually run `Update-Database` everything works as expected.

Is there a way to get this to run via code as I cant run Update-Database inside Azure.

Comment: `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true`?

Comment: I tried that, it didnt work, im pretty sure that setting is for automatically updating without migration files

Comment: You're wrong... `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled` manages, how migrations should be applied - either during context initialization or manually, using `Update-Database`. Of course, automatic migrations could be applied, if user account has sufficient rights to update database schema. What *exactly* didn't work with `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true`?

Comment: @denis I get the same exception. It definitely does work with this set false as it has been set to false since I added migrations to the solution. I've done plenty which worked correctly before now. CF http://elegantcode.com/2012/04/12/entity-framework-migrations-tips/

Comment: @denis also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806570/automaticmigrationsenabled-false-or-true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my (stupid) mistake, I hadn't changed the initialisation code but i had managed to deregister it so it wasn't getting called.

I moved it to the static constructor on my context and all was happy.

```
static MyContext()
{
    Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, Configuration>());
}
```