# Can not create tables in Firebird Database using Code First EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, firebird, entity-framework-migrations

I am new to Firebird database and I have a requirement where I have to integrate Firebird database with Code First Approach in Entity Framework MVC.

This is what I have done so far:

1. I added the connection string for Firebird database in App.Config
2. Passing that connection string in DBContext class
3. When I run update-database -force command in package manager console it creates Test.FDB database for me, but when I open this database, my tables were not created or migrated. I am using AutoMigrationsEnabled=true also.

Can you please provide a sample/example of creating Firebird database with MVC Code First approach and Entity Framework?

Answer (score 0):

First, check that your model classes are adding in the `DBContext` file, then you need to run `Add-Migration <YourMigrationName>` command from Package Manager Console then run `Update-Database`.

Sample code to add class to `DBContext`.

```
public virtual DbSet<YourClassName> YourClassName{ get; set; }
```

**Note:** You can try by using `AutoMigrationsEnabled=false`

You can refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11815229/6527049) why to use `AutoMigrationsEnabled=false`.